# Why is my MCP4822 DAC not outputting 0 V?

Tags: arduino, dac, midi

As part of my MIDI to CV project I am using an [MCP4822](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002249B.pdf) two-channel 12-bit DAC.

After much toil I have everything working as planned, except for the fact that even when initialised with values which should give an output of 0 V, the minimum I'm seeing at either V<sub>out</sub> is 0.56 V: that's half an octave I'm missing. Why is this happening?

```
void loop() {
  mode = digitalRead (modePin);      // GET MODE
  if (mode != prevMode) {
    setVoltage (DAC1, 0, 1, 0);       // INITIALISE BOTH DAC CHANNELS FOLLOWING MODE SWITCH
    setVoltage (DAC1, 1, 1, 0);
  }
  prevMode = mode;
  mode ? mode1() : mode2();
}

...
        
void setVoltage(int dacpin, bool channel, bool gain, unsigned int mV) {
  unsigned int command = channel ? 0x9000 : 0x1000;
  command |= gain ? 0x0000 : 0x2000;
  command |= (mV & 0x0FFF);
  
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(8000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

  digitalWrite(dacpin,LOW);

  SPI.transfer(command>>8);
  SPI.transfer(command&0xFF);

  digitalWrite(dacpin,HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
}
```

[image: ARDUINO > MCP4822]

Comment: is there an opamp in the signal path? Show us your schematic.

Comment: No op amp, just an Arduino, Optocoupler for the midi input and the DAC and a DMM

Comment: Are other values output correctly? And what happens in shutdown mode?

Comment: @CL Not using shutdown but I'll take a look . Max output is 4.569v which is about 0.5v  higher than the data sheet says for internal Vref at 2x gain.

Comment: This sounds like a 0.5 V offset. Is there any pullup? There might be a ground problem. Show your circuit.

Comment: @CL Schematic added. Not much to show really. The AT328 is an actual Arduino which is providing +5v and GND to the Dac and the Opto. The 8 pin package is a 4 way DIP switch for MIDI Channel selection. I'm currently looking at (per channel) two op-amps a bunch of resistors and two trimmers to get round this problem. If I can solve it in the code, (which should already initialise the DACs to 0v), I can get away with a single trimmer for the 1v/oct scaling.

Comment: What have you connected to MIDICV>CH1 and MIDICV>CH2?

Comment: @Chupacabras Nothing connected yet.... I'm just measuring at the DAC outputs.

Comment: Then I see only the problem with missing decoupling capacitor. See my answer.

Comment: @Chupacabras I tried the decoupling cap and it reduced the offset by only around 40mV. Anyhow, I was suspicious of the DAC and I managed to find a spare. It does not show this behaviour -  when initialised the new chip puts out just 2mV. So now my question is - Is this something i need to allow for in my design in order to compensate for inconsistency between devices (offset null trimmer) or was it just a duff chip? I'm guessing I need to buy a bunch of them and test.

Comment: Have you set the shutdown bit? So the device *isn't* isn't shut down?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using decoupling capacitors. That is usually causing such imprecision. Put at least 100nF decoupling capacitor to MCP4822.

Answer (score 1):

Since your \$V_{ref}\$ is set internally, I would try to trim it out by varying the voltage or I would try just using a diode in series that would forward bias on the ground pin.

Using a DAC with a single supply has never gave precise results either. The time I used that chip, I used a +/- 5 V supply project and I had a voltage divider between the +/- supply that went to my \$V_{ss}\$ pin. I do believe the \$V_{ss}\$ pin was around -0.6V or so.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was the GND connection to DAC pin 7. There was a cold solder joint.